# accessing unique id from master page dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get the unique id of dropdown list on master page in web forms cs code  `initialiseculture()`  function .

I tried using the unique id which i got by doing inspect element but still I'm unable to run code in a right way

this is the code in my master page

```
  <asp:DropDownList  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ID="selectDiffLang" ClientIDMode="Static">
  <asp:ListItem Value="en-US">English</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="ar-AE">Arabic</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

and this is the code in my web forms cs code i.e the initialiseculture() function

```
  protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        string cult = string.Empty;
        cult = Request["ctl00$selectDiffLang"];
        if ((cult != null) || (cult == ""))
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cult);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cult);

        }

        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `InitializeCulture` is called very early in the Page Lifecycle, you need to use the Form-property of the request to access the value:

```
// ...
cult = Request.Form["ctl00$selectDiffLang"];
// ...
```

Downside is that this will only work on PostBacks. For details see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

In order to also set the culture correctly also on GET requests, you need to implement a way to determine the culture based upon a previous setting or on the default for the user. As for the default, you could access the `Accept-Language` header and choose the culture based on this value.
If the user chooses a different language setting, you will get a PostBack and be able to determine the new value from the `Form` data. You should then apply the new culture and also store it either in the session or a cookie to make it available in subsequent GET requests.
Pseudo-code for selection the culture in `InitializeCulture`:

1. Do Form data contain a language setting? If yes, apply it and store it in Session/Cookie.
2. Does Session/Cookie contain a language setting? If yes, apply this setting.
3. Map the value of the `Accept-Language` header to a supported language and apply this setting.

Comment: request.form[id] part i tried and even now i tried this               if (Request.Form["ctl00$selectDiffLang"] != null)
            {
                cult = Request.Form["ctl00$selectDiffLang"];
                if ((cult != null) || (cult == ""))
                {
                       Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cult);
                       Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cult);
                }
            }                    It does'nt seem to work

Comment: @minu: is the ID correct? You can check Request.Form.AllKeys in the debugger to find the correct one. And - as I wrote - the data of the dropdownlist will only be present in a postback, not when you call the page in the browser. So change a value in the dropdownlist and retrieve the correct id then.

Comment: This above explanation whatever you gave me is the one for initialiseculture function rt?

Comment: @minu: yes, the pseudo-code is for `InitializeCulture`.